# Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found. with .net 4.7.2

Tags: c#

here is where the exeption is unhandled

```
CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(parameters, source);
```

here is the line where i set my compiler version

```
 Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.7.2" } };
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you get? Please show the complete text.

Comment: There is only one compiler (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe), you must use "v4.0" to select it.

Comment: Please provide us minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example